# Two jQuery-UI inline datepickers on page, second one doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm calling inline datepickers like so (simplified version for demo purposes):

```
<input id="inp_datepicker" name="startDateField">
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<input id="inp_datepicker2" name="endDateField">
<div id="datepicker2"></div>
```

And I've added this to the Javascript so they will put the result of the selection into an editable field.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#inp_datepicker')[0].value = convertDateToString(dateObject);
    }
});

$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#inp_datepicker2')[0].value = convertDateToString(dateObject);
    }
});
```

Everything works fine **except** the second datepicker doesn't populate the second field. First one, no problem. Second one, nothing.

I set a breakpoint in the second onSelect function and find that it doesn't break there at all.

(I know, I could circumvent this by just having the input pop up the calendar, and all that worked fine in the past, but this time the PRD specifies *inline* datepickers, so I have to assign the result of the selection to a field.) Again, the first one works fine.

**EDIT** Removed `class="hasDatepicker"` from divs because that's not in the source, only in the rendered markup after jQuery-UI datepicker does its thing.

**EDIT 2** I'm embarrassed to say that I have fixed the problem myself. It seems it was related to another, unrelated script that had nothing to do with datepickers. After removing that script, it all worked, even though the script was throwing no errors. Ah, what would we do without legacy code, yeah? Also, I think it would probably be best to delete this post so nobody wastes any more time on it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Could you provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Dom: Would that I could, but this is all extracted out of JSP pages.

Comment: No worries, could you provide `convertDateToString` function?

Comment: Nope, no error in the console.

Comment: show convertDateToString function...

Comment: How can you bind `datepicker` to a div?

Comment: @HarshitTailor: I don't have a problem showing it, but if it's not getting called in the second instance and it works in the first, what's the point?

Comment: @user1479606 you can bind to div when doing inline: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: @user1479606 [Just the way the docs say](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) (as I demonstrate above). That works fine in the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem stems from class `.hasDatepicker`.

```
<div id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker"></div>
<div id="datepicker2" class="hasDatepicker"></div>
```

When you call `.datepicker()`, it automatically adds `.hasDatepicker`.  If that class already exists, then it will assume datepicker has already been added.

EXAMPLE:
http://jsbin.com/ukotit/27/edit

Remove the class from the `div`s and it should work.

```
$("#datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#inp_datepicker')[0].value = convertDateToString(dateObject);
    }
});

$("#datepicker2").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#inp_datepicker2')[0].value = convertDateToString(dateObject);
    }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/ukotit/30/edit

---

***UPDATE:***

```
$("#datepicker, #datepicker2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $(this).prev()[0].value = dateText;
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ukotit/32/edit

Comment: I'm not adding the ".hasDatepicker" class. I just copied that from the rendered source. On the JSP page I don't have a class on that div at all, so it must be getting added after the fact. Also, your demo also doesn't have a convertDateToString function, but I would settle for a 1 or a 2 to be placed in the field for demo purposes.

Comment: Hmm very strange... okay I will update my answer in a little. Have one more idea.

Comment: @Robusto I made changes to my post, let me know if that works.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I have fixed the problem myself. It seems it was related to another script that had nothing to do with datepickers. After removing that script, it all worked, even though the script was throwing no errors. Ah, what would we do without legacy code, yeah?

Comment: @Robusto Haha all good, glad you fixed the problem! Troubleshooting is always such a pain.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have your datepicker on the div not the input.

You could rework this simpler as:

Add data to elemnet and use it.

```
<input id="inp_datepicker" data-relatedelementid="datepicker" type="text" name="startDateField">
<div id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker"></div>
<input id="inp_datepicker2" data-relatedelementid="datepicker2"  type="text" name="endDateField">
<div id="datepicker2" class="hasDatepicker"></div>

$("#inp_datepicker,#inp_datepicker2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#'+$(this).data('relatedelementid')).text(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have it on the div because that's how you display the datepicker inline, as I say in my question.

Comment: It needs to be inline, so you need to call `.datepicker()` on a `div`.